# Error after App Store Connect submision. ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an App that integrates **Framework A** that I have developed.

Framework A has two (optional) weak-linked third-party dependencies, **Framework X** and **Framework Y**.

If I add both optional frameworks, everything works fine.

I don't need Framework **Y** in my App, so I'm adding to MyApp only Framework **A** and **X**.

Run on device works fine, upload to TestFlight works fine, but then I'm getting this email from App Store Connect, and build is marked as an Invalid Binary on App Store Connect.

> App Store Connect   Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are
> referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.
>
> ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - The app submission can not be
> successfully recompiled from bitcode due to missing symbols during
> linking. You can try to reproduce and diagnose such issues locally by
> following the instructions from:
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

---

I have tried editing Build Settings, but nothing happened, the error stays.

How I removed that error was by **disabling Bitcode**. Build Settings - Enable Bitcode - NO.

**But that is not a solution for me.**

I saw the same question on the Apple Developer forum. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88814

---

After that, I tried to Validate App in the organizer, which went well. After that, I tried to export IPA for AdHoc distribution. But then I got an error:

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool -v -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin -L /var/folders/cy/n0fltmsx671_s97kbtqvhcw80000gn/T/ipatool20220308-33623-uqn6vl/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FrameworkY.framework -L /var/folders/cy/n0fltmsx671_s97kbtqvhcw80000gn/T/ipatool20220308-33623-uqn6vl/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FrameworkX.framework --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk -o /var/folders/cy/n0fltmsx671_s97kbtqvhcw80000gn/T/ipatool20220308-33623-uqn6vl/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA --generate-dsym /var/folders/cy/n0fltmsx671_s97kbtqvhcw80000gn/T/ipatool20220308-33623-uqn6vl/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA.dSYM --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/cy/n0fltmsx671_s97kbtqvhcw80000gn/T/ipatool20220308-33623-uqn6vl/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA
```

I saw a similar error in this post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663112

If at export I disable Bitcode, I'm able to export the IPA file.

---

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or is there a bug on Apple's side with Bitcode, but I hope that maybe someone had the same problem.

Comment: "How I removed that error was by disabling Bitcode." Seems obvious from the error message. "But that is not a solution for me." Whyever not? I've never known Bitcode to be good for anything. I never enable it. It causes nothing but slowness and trouble (like yours).

Answer (score 0):

Removing Bitcode is not a good approach since it will not slim the ipas for installation.

What I'm doing at the moment is to **use Xcode 13.2.1 for the upload** of my project.